# Material Design WPF TextBox Validation error message change position when scrolling page

Tags: wpf, material-design

I'm new in Material Design. Could someone, please, explain me how can I fix a bug with validation message in textbox
[image]

Validation error shows uncorrectly - changes position when I'm scrolling view.
Here is code from .xaml

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="11"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Width="20"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 materialDesign:ValidationAssist.UsePopup="True"
                 materialDesign:ValidationAssist.OnlyShowOnFocus="True"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 ToolTip="Use a popup which can escape the bounds of the control where space is limited">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="Name"
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <helpers:NotEmptyValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

**This Validation TextBox uses data binding behind the scenes to work. The code is correct but you might be missing the data binding on the Name.**

```
    <Binding Path="Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
```

For this, to work you need to data bind the path to the Name property.

This can be done in two steps.

1. Create/reuse a property **Name** in the desired class.
2. Assign the data context of the XAML page to the desired class.

*Sample (desired class is shown as MainWindow here)*

Step 1, file: **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
```

Step 2, file: **MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        ...
    }
```

And then the problem should be solved.

Comment: Can you mark this as an answer if this is what you were looking for?

Comment: I have DataContext = new TextFieldsViewModel(); in view code behind. And TextFieldsViewModel has property Name. Problem with validation error placement on page.

Comment: Try adjusting: **`materialDesign:HintAssist.FloatingOffset`** and/or **`materialDesign:ValidationAssist.PopupPlacement`** in the _Textbox_.

Comment: Also Try **,materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.TextBoxViewMargin="? ? ? ?",**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just remove:

```
materialDesign:ValidationAssist.UsePopup="True"
```